# Use asp-validation-for without binding to model property

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-validators

In the past I have always used the following code to make something globally clear, like with a login form, when the username or the password are not correct. I dont want this error message to link to a specific model property like Username or Password, but just a custom ValidationMessage.

*Controller:*

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Combination", "Password or username not correct.");
```

*View:*

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("Combination")
```

In the new examples that are generated with VS17 it uses not 
`@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` and `@Html.ValidationMessage()` anymore, but the easier
`<span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>`

Now the problem occurs that I cannot find anything like `asp-validation="Combination"` that replaces the `@Html.ValidationMessage()`.

Is it totally different, did I miss something, or do I need to use the old `@Html.ValidationMessage()` as an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a "global" validation error, you can simply use an empty string to specify that the error does not relate to a specific property:

```cs
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Password or username not correct.");
```

With this in place, you can use the [`asp-validation-summary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-validation-tag-helpers) tag-helper to generate your message (or messages - you can call `AddModelError` multiple times with `string.Empty`):

```html
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
```

By specifying `ModelOnly`, only those validation messages you added using `string.Empty` will be shown.